# Z-Spread vs Discount Margin

Tags: fixed-income, pricing, self-study, discounting

I'm comparing two types of discounting: Z-Spread and Discount Margin.

Reading the article by O'Kane [Credit Spread Explained](http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Lehman%20Brothers,%20O%27Kane]%20Credit%20Spreads%20Explained.pdf) I found Z-Spread is used for fixed rate notes meanwhile Discount Margin, and Z-DM, are used for floating rate notes.

I got the two definitions:

- **Z-Spread**: vertical parallel shift over the current *zero rate curves*
- **Discount Margin**: vertical shift over the *current XIBOR*

My question is: why theoretically speaking is more correct to use Discount Margin for floating rate notes meanwhile I should use Z-Spread for fixed rate ones?

For floating rate notes, is it also correct to use the *current zero rate curve* for discounting and the *forward curve* for generating future cashflows?

Answer (score 1):

For floating-rate bonds, it is difficult to compute z-spread if you don't know their cash flows. As a result, you would use discount margin where you have an assumption for the future cash flows of the floater.